# Material tabs change to last tab when selectedIndex is higher than the actual number of tabs

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

For example, I have 2 tabs in my mat-tab-group:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Let's say the first tab is chosen (index 0), when I change selectedIndex to 2 (which should switch to tab 3 but it doesn't exist) the second tab is chosen. I want the first tab to remain selected because the index was out of range. How can I do that? (For a generic case: `n` number of tabs, one of them selected (not necessarily the first or last one, and `selectedIndex>n`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

In TS:

```
let index = this.Activeroute.snapshot.queryParams['index'];

if(selectedIndex > n)
{
   this.selectedIndex = 0;
}
else
{
   this.selectedIndex = index;
}
```

Comment: Activeroute is not recognized by my VSCode